# keep decimal places when converting df to csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to keep the decimal place as it is when converting a dataframe into csv file?
For example, this is how my dataframe looks like:

[image]

When I tried to convert using 
`df.to_csv('C:/Users/data/data.csv', index=False)`, my output for value became 1.0 or 0.0, instead of 1 or 0. 
I cannot use `('C:/Users/data/data.csv', float_format="%.0f', index=False)`, because that makes my `version` variable lose decimal places. 
How can I preserve the original data, without adding or losing decimal places? I have many other value columns, value1, value2,..valuen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change dtype of your second column to the integer before:

```
import numpy as np

df["value"] = df["value"].astype(np.int)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! But what if there are many "value"s? value1, value2, .....value100. any easier way to change them all at one time?

Answer (score 0):

To convert many integer columns at once, first initialize them and then convert them to float.

```
# Initialize integer columns
integer_cols=list(df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'int32']).columns)

# Change all of them to float
df[integer_cols] = df[integer_cols].astype('float')
```